# Direction of normal vector on spacelike foliation

Tags: general-relativity, adm-formalism

Let $(\Sigma_t)_{t\in\mathbf{R}}$ be a spacelike hypersurface foliation of our spacetime $(\mathcal{M},g_{\mu\nu})$.
Let $n^\mu$ be the future-directed unit normal to the hypersurface $\Sigma_t$. Thus, it must be parallel to the gradient of t,
with the proportionality factor $\alpha$, which we call the lapse function $\alpha$,

\begin{align}
    n_\mu := -\alpha\nabla_\mu t = -\alpha\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)_\mu = -\alpha\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\0\\0\end{array}\right).
\end{align}

Due to $\Sigma_t$ being a spacelike hypersurface and $n_\mu$ having unit length we know $n^\mu n_\mu = -1$. Thus, the lapse function must be,

\begin{align}
    n^\mu n_\mu &= g^{\mu\nu}n_\mu n_\nu = g^{00} (-\alpha)^2 = -1\\
    &\Rightarrow  \alpha = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g^{00}}}
\end{align}

Question: So far, the minus sign in $n_\mu := -\alpha\nabla_\mu t$ is arbitrary and everything would work out exactly the same without it. The only thing I found is that we want $n_\mu$ to point in the same direction in which $t$ increases. However, intuitively I would say that $t$ increases in the $\partial/\partial t = (1,0,0,0)^T$ direction and thus the zero component of $n_\mu$ should be positive. The way it is now its zero component is negative, due to $\alpha>0$.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $n$ with a lowered index, meaning you're really looking at the form $n_\mu dx^\mu$. If you instead worked with a raised index, so you're really using the vector field $n^\mu\partial_\mu$, will then be exactly  $\partial_t$ with the desired sign (assuming your matric has been locally diagonalized, which it needs to be for the components you've specified to be as they are).

Generally, coordinates have raised indices, $x^\mu$. While well-defined, I would assert that it's bad form to lower indices on coordinates as it can cause confusions like you have here.

Comment: +1 In my opinion, downstairs indices on coordinates are well-defined only in the weakest possible sense - as shorthand for a meaningless collection of numbers. Literally the only value that they possess is that it is possible to reconstruct the actual coordinates of a spacetime point from them if you are also given the metric components. It’s like building a road to a location whose only significance is that if you turn around, you can get back to where you started. </rant>